# Mudar as propriedades de um objeto SVG com JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onclick, gráfico

Eu estou aprendendo sobre criação de gráficos **SVG** para HTML e gostaria de saber como posso **mudar as propriedades de um objeto** **SVG** (line, cicle, rect) através de **JS** por exemplo, ao clicar em um botão ele mudar a posição de uma line. procurei em alguns sites e não encontrei.

Desde já, Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode mudar as propriedades do SVG com JavaScript alterando os atributos com `setAttribute`:

```js
function alterarSvg(){
   var svg_line = document.querySelector("#meusvg line"); // seleciono o line do SVG

   svg_line.setAttribute("x2","10"); // muda posição x2
   svg_line.setAttribute("stroke","blue"); // muda a cor para azul
}
```

```html
<svg id="meusvg" width="100" height="100">
   <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="alterarSvg()">Clique-me</button>
```

Comment: Cara eu tive uma duvida complementar a isso, se eu usar <text> eu posso alterar o texto desse espaço com JS ? assim como posso alterar o texto de um <p> com DOM

Comment: Pode sim. Mesma coisa